# Firebase C++ realtime database connection lost on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, firebase, networking, firebase-realtime-database

I have been using Firebase C++ SDK's Auth and Realtime Database (for Windows) in a simple test application. After a succesful authentication every new message (node) is being arrived from the cloud within just a few millisecs until the following happens:

1. I leave my computer untouched in idle state.
2. Due to the energy settings it goes to sleep after 10-15 minutes. (don't want to change the settings!)
3. After I wake it up again the network connection is re-established for all other background applications (like Skype, Outlook etc)
4. It seems Firebase's connection is NOT re-established.

Is there any built-in function to get notification from Firebase when it's lost the connection and try to re-login, re-connect to the database either automatically or manually?

I guess it has a background keep-alive connection to check network status but I couldn't get any useful information about it. The documentation says it can keep everything synced even in offline mode.

Comment: The Firebase Database client is supposed to auto-reconnect (with exponential backoff). You might want to [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/cpp/class/firebase/database/database#classfirebase_1_1database_1_1_database_1a572cf0e0327c87e7a6a36f270dfec16b) and then check the logging output to see if that's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> any built-in function to get notification from Firebase when it's lost the connection[?]

For that you'd attach a listener to the virtual `.info/connected` node, as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state. Somehow this section is missing from the C++ documentation, which is why I linked you to the Android version.

Comment: Thank you so much! Connection/disconnection events are triggered ;)

Comment: Good to hear Peter. I have no idea why they aren't documented for C++ and Unity, so you might want to leave feedback in that documentation page.